# Как заставить работать подгрузку комментариев посредством AJAX при загрузке jquery с атрибутом defer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-events

У меня возникла проблема с подгрузкой комментариев AJAX(при скролее страницы вниз) и кнопкой добавления комментариев,после того как подключил jquery не синхронно, а с атрибутом defer, после этого комментарии перестали подгружатся и добавлятся, а в консоле появилась ошибка jQuery is not defined , jquery подключается в самом верху в head, а тег {AJAX} который выводит нужные функции в HTML прописан сразу после открывающегося тега body
порядок подключения внешних скриптов в head следующий:

```
<script  defer src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script  defer src="/js/jqueryui.js"></script>
<script  defer src="/js/dle_js.js"></script>
<script  defer src="/js/masha.js"></script>
<script  defer src="/js/libs.js"></script>
<script  defer src="/js/waypoints.js"></script>
```

После просмотра в исходном коде страницы я установил, что эти 2 функции подключаются таким образом:

```
jQuery(function($){
    var dle_news_id= '12';
    var total_comments_pages= '3';
    var current_comments_page= '1';

/*Это функция AJAX подгрузки комментарие при прокрутке*/
$('.ajax_comments_next').waypoint(function() {

        if (current_comments_page < total_comments_pages ) {

            $.waypoints('disable');
            current_comments_page ++;
            ShowLoading('');

            $.get(dle_root + "engine/ajax/controller.php?mod=comments", { cstart: current_comments_page, news_id: dle_news_id, skin: dle_skin, massact:'disable' }, function(data){

                setTimeout(function() { $.waypoints('enable'); }, 300);
                HideLoading('');

                $(".ajax_loaded_comments").append(data.comments);

            }, "json");

        } else {

            $.waypoints('destroy');
        }


    }, {
      offset: 'bottom-in-view'
    });

/*Это функция подтвержления добавления комментария*/
$('#dle-comments-form').submit(function() {
    doAddComments();
    return false;
});
});
```

функцию подтверждения добавления комментария я добавил прямо в кнопку в HTML

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" onclick="jQuery(function($){$('#dle-comments-form').submit(function() {doAddComments();return false;});});">Отправить</button>
```

работает отлично, дальше я попытался вставить функцию подгрузки комментариев в HTML непсредственно перед местом отображения навигации , это не сработало, потом я подумал что будет отлично, если я и эту функцию добавлю в кнопку, по аналогии с первым примером я попытался добавить и эту функцию в onclick()

```
onclick="jQuery(function($ {$('.ajax_comments_next').waypoint(function());"
```

это не сработало,потом пробовал вставить всю функцию в событие (как в исходном коде страницы), тоже безрезультатно.
Подскажите, как мне заставить эту функцию работать по клику кнопки? не совсем понимаю, что делаю не так, ведь с кнопкой отправки комментария все получилось

Comment: Если ставите `defer` на `jquery`, то инлайновый js еще не знает о его существовании. Он появляется в `window` после обработки `html`.

Comment: @Artem Gorlachev, но когда я вставил в кнопку onclick с функцией подтверждения добавления комментария, все хорошо работает, а вот с подгрузкой не хочет работать, получается, в первом случае знает а во втором нет? хотя я читал по поводу этого и пробовал вставлять в кнопку при помощи jQuery(document).ready(function($) {$('.ajax_comments_next').waypoint(function()); });

Answer (score 0):

Видимо ты занимаешься оптимизацией.
Предлагаю такое решение [тынц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638221/load-jquery-with-javascript-using-promises)

Так если загружать Jquery через promises и все свои js скрипты обернуть в

```
loadjQuery().then(function() {
// code here that uses jQuery}, function() {
// error loading jQuery});
```

Прочти ответ по ссылке и все поймешь.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, я действительно оптимизирую страницу, попробовал сделать как описано в том ответе, загрузка jquery таким образом как и defer не блокирует рендеринг но ничего не изменилось та же ошибка jQuery is not defined ,подгрузка комментариев не работает, хотя функцию завернул в loadjQuery().then(function() { });

Comment: я к тому, что с оптимизацией все продвигается как планировалось, но меня интересует почему есть 2 функции, одна работает по клику на кнопку а другая нет, при равных условиях?

Comment: пример можете сделать или где можно посмотреть, так как я не могу не посмотрев на всю картину ответить.

Comment: если не трудно посмотрите по ссылке ниже, там получается в исходном коде на 391 строке кнопка которая работает после добавления в нее функции, а на 668 там кнопка которая не хочет работать, да и сама AJAX навигация там же http://lfxw4gjd-site.ftempurl.com/interview/12-devjataja-novost-tozhe-doinnaja-i-ona-dlinaaja.html

Comment: уберите с button onclick, перенесите в ваш js файл, добавьте идентификатор для submit и сделайте так `$( document ).on( "click", "#buttonId", function(){ // здесь делаете вызов функции подгрузки комментариев  } );`

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать все это